# Draw route on MKMapView that looks like Maps app

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

I have no problem getting and drawing the route with the following code

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {

    switch overlay {
    case let overlay as MKPolyline:
        let renderer = MKPolylineRenderer(polyline: overlay)
        renderer.strokeColor = UIColor(red: 59, green: 164, blue: 252)
        renderer.lineWidth = 3
        return renderer
    default: return MKOverlayRenderer()
    }
}
```

But the problem is, this looks very poor compared to the maps app. First of all, the line width doesn't scale with the zoom level, so it looks weird from too far or too close, and second, I cannot find how to imitate Apple's slightly darker border on the outside and lighter filling on the inside.

All the questions I could find only set a basic color and line width and that's it, does anyone have experience with something a little fancier?